# Faster way to find the closest pair of points

Tags: performance, algorithm

I'm trying to compare all elements of an array to each other. I can do it with nested loops but it's a very inefficient algorithm and I can tell it's not the right way to do it. Here's what I'm doing right now.

PER answers below I've changed this code and I'm expanding on the question.

```
// Point from java.awt.Point;
private static void findShortestDistance(Point[] pt) {

  ArrayList<Double> distance = new ArrayList<Double>(1000);    

  for(int i=0; i<pt.length; i++) {
    for(int j=i+1; j<pt.length; j++) {
      double tmp = pt[i].distance(pt[j]);
      distance.add(tmp);        
    }
  }

  double min = distance.get(0);
  for(Double d : distance) {
    if(d < min) { min = d; }
  }

}
```

There's the full code for the method I have so far. I'm trying to find the shortest distance between two points in the given array.

Comment: start the second loop with j = i+1 ?

Comment: What kind of comparisons do you need? Transitive?

Comment: @MatthewVines No it's an array of Points (from java.awt). I'm running the distance formula and putting the resulting distances in a List so I can find the shortest distance between the given points.

Comment: @CaldwellYSR - Can you post your complete code `/* do stuff */`? I am not sure what your are trying to do.

Comment: You mean you want min of dist(pt[i], pt[j])? There is an algorithm using divide and conquer, O(nlogn)

Comment: @sch Edited with all the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at wikipedia.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points

And this question seems to be the same as
[Shortest distance between points algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602164/shortest-distance-between-points-algorithm)

Comment: Ah... Well it seems my entire method was wrong haha! Thanks for the info. I'll accept this answer as the correct one since it answers the question behind my original question.

Comment: Sorry for not describing the detail of this algorithm. I don't remember it very well.

Comment: That's okay, I'd like to figure out the actual code if at all possible. I'm still learning this stuff. Thanks for the wiki link, that will help alot.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing `j` to `i+1` will skip the redundant comparisons.

```
for(int i = 0; i < pt.length; i++) {
  for(int j = i + 1; j < pt.length; j++) {
    if(pt[i] != pt[j]) { /* do stuff */ }
  }
}
```

(BTW, changed the if-statement, assuming you meant to use `i` and `j` as indexes into an array.)

That's about the best you can get for the most basic case where you need to get a cross product of the array with itself, minus all the elements `{x, y} | x == y`.  (i.e. an exhaustive list of unordered pairs of differing elements.)  If you need ordered pairs of differing elements, then your code is best.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you say the above code is exactly what you want the following will be the implementation you want:

```
for(int i=0; i<pt.length; i++) {
  for(int j = i + 1; j<pt.length; j++) {
     /* do stuff */
  }
}
```

However, I have a god feeling you are actually interested in comparing the array values or am I wrong?

Comment: Actually I'm running `pt[i].distance(pt[j]);` to set up a List of distances so I can find the shortest distance between a given list of points.

Comment: You can do that faster using KD tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree. In case of 2D points it will reduce your algorithm from O(n^2) to O(n* sqrt(n))

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<pt.length; i++) {
  for(int j=i+1; j<pt.length; j++) {
    if(pt[i] != pt[j]) { /* do stuff */ }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<pt.length; i++) {
  for(int j=i; j--; ) {
     { /* do stuff */ }
  }
}
```

And, for completeness:

```
for(int i=pt.length; i--; ) {
  for(int j=i; j--; ) {
     { /* do stuff */ }
  }
}
```