# Algorithm to find shortest distance from a point in set A to points in set B

Tags: c, algorithm

There a set A with n 3d points (x,y,z) and set B with m 3d points (x,y,z).
For each point (Xi,Yi,Zi) in set A we have to find a point in set B that has minimum distance from (Xi,Yi,Zi).

My code is running out of given time limit. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
long long np[50000][3],qp[50000][3];
int main()
{
long long n,q,i,j,d,ans,min;
scanf("%lld",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%lld%lld%lld",&np[i][0],&np[i][0],&np[i][2]);
scanf("%lld",&q);
for(i=0;i<q;i++)
scanf("%lld%lld%lld",&qp[i][0],&qp[i][1],&qp[i][2]);
for(i=0;i<q;i++)
{
    ans=0;
    min=((qp[i][0]-np[0][0])*(qp[i][0]-np[0][0]))+((qp[i][1]-np[0][1])*(qp[i][1]-qp[0][1]))+((qp[i][2]-np[0][2])*(qp[i][2]-np[0][2]));
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        d=((qp[i][0]-np[j][0])*(qp[i][0]-np[j][0]))+((qp[i][1]-np[j][1])*(qp[i][1]-qp[j][1]))+((qp[i][2]-np[j][2])*(qp[i][2]-np[j][2]));
        if(d<min)
        {
            ans=j;
            min=d;
        }
    }
    printf("%lld\n",ans);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's the given time limit??

Comment: Take a look at [Shortest distance between points algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602164/shortest-distance-between-points-algorithm).

Comment: Please provide more details.  Is your code faulty and infinitely looping, or does it work for smaller datasets and just takes too much time for larger datasets?

Comment: @james time limit is 7 sec and n=m=50000

Comment: It's a pet peeve, but could you please properly indent your code when posting?

Comment: @mbeckish my code is correct. its just algorithm i think is not fast enough, and hence my code is not feasible for large data set.

Answer (score 2):

You're using an O(n^2) algo. I doubt that is fast enough. For some ways to do it faster, check out [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem).

Or more specifically, you can use the divide an conquer approach described in that article, which is relatively straightforward if you're comfortable with recursion. Since you are dealing with z axis, you'll have to extend the algo described there to use 2 dividing lines (one for x axis, then one for y), so it's going to be a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a [nearest neighbour triangulation](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs368-06-spring/handouts/Delaunay_1.pdf) from either set which is O(n log n), then use something like a [proximity search](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/C.B.Jones/JonesWareCJ98.pdf) to drape each point in turn from the other set onto the triangulation to find it's nearest neighbour.  For doing this type of thing in C, [Joseph O'Rourkes book](http://books.google.ie/books/about/Computational_Geometry_in_C.html?id=gsv7HALW2jYC&redir_esc=y) is going to be well worth reading.