# Heuristics for A* algorithm in a weighted graph

Tags: javascript, algorithm, shortest-path, heuristics

I'm making an app for a school project that finds the shortest path between 2 room on the campus. there're 100+ rooms so I don't think Dijkstra can be used. all the heuristics I've found so far are for game path finding. Can I use these? What's the best heuristic to use for this?

Comment: Rectangular distance usually isn't a bad choice for traversing a 4-direction grid from node to node. For 8 directions consider diagonal distance, and free traversal maybe try euclidean distance. Each of these basically just keep the algorithm "pointing" at the goal

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if its 100% related , but there is some good detailed anwser on shortest-distance between points in here:

[Shortest distance between points algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602164/shortest-distance-between-points-algorithm)