# What's the best approach to take the coordinates from each object (x,y) and calculate the distance between them?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

```
const destinations = [
{
    id: 0,
    city: "Buenos Aires",
    country: "Argentina",
    codeIATA: "AEP",
    aeroName: "Aeroparque Jorge Newbery",
    coordX: 15,
    coordY: 36,
},
{
    id: 1,
    city: "El Calafate",
    country: "Argentina",
    codeIATA: "FTE",
    aeroName: "Comandante A. Tola",
    coordX: -49,
    coordY: -63,
},
```

With an array of several objects that constitute cities/airports like the 2 objects above,
the user will have to select one object as origin and the other as destination. What I'm trying to find out is how to catch the x and y coordinates of each chosen origin and destination to calculate the distance between the two points and be able to provide distance in km, time and flight cost.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602164/shortest-distance-between-points-algorithm

Comment: when you receive the source point and destination point via canvas/dropdowns etc. You can use the formula to calculate the distance between two points:
`const xDes = 0;`
`const xSour = -1;`
`const yDes = 5;`
`const ySour = -2;`
`Math.sqrt((xDes - xSour)^2 + (yDes - ySour)^2)`

Comment: @Skalpel02 These are geocoordinates, not euler coordinates

Comment: Flight time and cost depends on many more things than just distance.